# Extract all text regardless of tags with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

****EDITED TO ADD ROOT ELEMENT IN THE XML (and it changes nothing)****
I'm using python 3.7 
I have an xml file named 'f':

```
<root>
 <page>
  <title>Chapter 1</title>
  <content>Welcome to Chapter 1</content>
 </page>
 <page>
  <title>Chapter 2</title>
  <content>Welcome to Chapter 2</content>
 </page>
</root>
```

****ALSO EDITED TO ADD This is part of a bigger code and for reasons the content of the file 'f' is in a type:

```
<class 'nt.DirEntry'>
```

And I got this type by grabbing the file from a folder using

```
for folder in os.scandir(folderPath):
```

****

I want to extract every piece of text in that xml regardless of the tags and how they are nested.
So I would have :

> Chapter 1 
>   Welcome to Chapter 1 
>   Chapter 2 
>   Welcome to Chapter 2

I tried:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(f)
root = tree.getroot()
root.text #returns nothing
#or
root.tostring() #returns AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'tostring'
```

and I tried:

```
tree = ET.fromstring(f)
print(''.join(tree.itertext())) #returns TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'nt.DirEntry'
```

thank you!

Comment: added root, it changes nothing to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to provide the filename as a string. In this case, `f` is a `os.DirEntry` object whose path is `f.path`.
- `itertext()` is a method on `Element` objects.

Demo:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(f.path)
root = tree.getroot()
print(''.join(root.itertext()))
```

Output:

```
Chapter 1
Welcome to Chapter 1


Chapter 2
Welcome to Chapter 2
```

Comment: the content of the f file is in the type <class 'nt.DirEntry'>

Comment: it's a file in a folder I grabbed using "for folder in os.scandir(folderPath):"

Comment: I'm sorry I did't know about this. I"ll do it. Thanks y'all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
tree = et.parse('input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for it in root.iter():
    txt = it.text.strip()
    if txt:
        print(txt)
```

The reason to use *strip* and *if* is to filter out printing of elements with
no text or containing only "white" characters.

Look at the other answer. It contains 2 empty lines.
But my solution is free from such flaws.